# How to plot binary data together with continuous data in time series with ggplot2?

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, time-series, binary-data

I have several data sets containing binary and continuous data respectively.
The data sets includes the datetime for the given observation.
The time step in the datetime column is not the same, so I cannot merge the datasets.
(So far I kept the two datasets apart, especially because the timestep in each dataset is irregular it itself.)
The binary data is in lower frequency than the continous data

Important: I transformed the time to POSIXct format in order to get around the irregular timesteps in the data

I would like to plot the two datasets in one time series plot with ggplot2.
The binary data (0's and 1's) should shade the continuous curve with rectangular surfaces going from y=-Inf to y=Inf. 
Does it make sense?

My question: How do I do that?

How to I create a legend and control the colors of the plot?

So far I have the binary data in one plot using geom_step
and the continous data in another plot

I tried multiplot, but it does not seem to work.
The dream situation is, to put multiple plots of different data on top of each other as layers using the POSIXct time as reference somehow!

Comment: Provide some reproducible example with your code

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputations to post a picture of the kind of plot I want to make...

Comment: Maybe this works: http://www.bygningsfysik.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Skærmbillede-2015-02-04-kl.-10.21.46.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can give some reproducible code..

This is how I transform the time column to POSIXct format:

`D$Time <- strptime(D$Time, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")`

This is the plot with two binary data sets using geom_step:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=E, aes(x=Time, y=Set, group=1, col="high window")) +
  geom_step(data=D, aes(x=Time, y=Set, group=1)) +
  scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct('0015-01-07 08:00:00'), as.POSIXct('0015-01-07 10:00:00'))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 1))
```

I am currently trying to plot the plot above together with a third dataset which is continuous, which means I need another y-axis if I should continue with geom_step...